# How arrange columns in sp_whoisactive by Adam Machanic

Tags: sql-server-2008

I really like using sp_whoisactive v11.11 by Adam Machanic. But when then info is displayed, the DB name is at the very end. I would like it to in the very first columns so I don't have to scroll everytime... Does anyone have suggestions to arrange columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the line with @output_column_list declared on it and put [database_name] between [dd%] and [session_id].

When I scripted it out it was on line 110.

Comment: Thanks Guys.. let me give it a try and get back to you...

Comment: Thank you for helping me mrdenny and SQL Kiwi... appreciate taking your time to assist. I was going through the whole code and tweeking different parts of the code except for line 110.

Answer (score -3):

Change the code. Or ask Adam Machanic to change it.

Comment: I played with it but couldn't make any progress... I have asked him too but most probably he is busy